# Create dialog based on console output

Tags: shell-script, tomcat, notifications, dialog, zenity

I would like to display a dialog box using zenity or dialog or something similar based on a specific string displayed in console window?

Background:
I have created a wrapper shell script which calls Tomcat 7 catalina.sh. I want to display a info box with a OK message when "Server startup in XXXXXms" is outputted to the console. I dont want to edit the catalina.sh as its prone to changes or overwritting. So I need to do this in wrapper shell script.

Is the above possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely untested:

```
/path/to/catalina.sh 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    if [[ $line == *"Server startup in"* ]]; then
        dialog --msgbox "$message" 10 40
    fi
done
```

Comment: Should message be line?

Comment: That is a question for @Anas to answer.